# vim-colourscheme - git update server info on the server?

Tags: git, github, vim, vim-plugin

I have installed few Vim plugins through vundle and now I am trying to install flazz/vim-colorschemes. The corresponding line in .vimrc I had was `Plugin 'flazz/vim-colourschemes'`, as mentioned in the git page.
And, when i run `:PluginInstall`, it asks me github username and password. After providing the password i get something as follows

```
fatal: https://github.com/flazz/vim-colourschemes.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

Can anybody please help me in setting this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long struggle I found a way, don't know this is the correct way, but it worked.
The corresponding line on .vimrc i had as follows:

- **previously (version that was *not* working):**
             `Plugin 'flazz/vim-colourschemes'`
- **now (working version):**
             `Plugin 'https://github.com/flazz/vim-colorschemes'`